# How to fade in a ListItem if ListItem is of a certain type

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a ListBox, with some ListItems inside. All of the ListItems inherit from my BaseViewModel (using MVVM)

What I'd like to do is if the ListItem is is of type DogViewModel (which inherits BaseViewModel), then for the ListItem to fade in. If the LIstItem is of type CatViewModel, then it will have no 'special' effects.

Initially, all values are of type cat, but the user change the type to a dog, at which point I'd like to see the original fade out and the new fade in. For the moment, I'm only focusing on the fade in.

The code below does not compile, but I'm hoping it will show what I'm trying to achieve (and what I've tried)

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Group}" Value="{x:Type vm:DogVm}">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The problem with the above is it removes my ListItem totally (or makes it invisible, not sure which)

How can I specify in that, in XAML only, that if the item which has just been added to the ObseravableCollection is of N, then fade in?

Comment: Please note, just because I'm animating the Dog now doesn't mean I won't give equal treatment to the Cat later, so Cat lovers please remain calm

Answer (score 0):

I think DataTrigger instead of EventTrigger is more suitable and you need to use x:Type to specify the bound data to the Item.

Edit:
I answered your question based on your original post. Now, given your current code, I suggest to use a converter.

Here, I have chosen my ItemTemplate to be a Button.

```
<Window.Resources>
     <d:ObjectToTypeConverter x:Key="convertToType" />
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
        <Button x:Name="btn" Content="{Binding Name}"></Button>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger 
                 Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource convertToType}}" Value="{x:Type d:DogVm}">
                    <Setter TargetName="btn" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource convertToType}}" Value="{x:Type d:CatVm}">
                 <Setter TargetName="btn" Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

and here is the converter ...

```
public class ObjectToTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.GetType();
    }
      .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use DataTemplateSelector. Here is an implementation:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="FirstTemplate">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=YourProperty}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="SecondTemplate">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=YourProperty}" Background="Red"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

and DataTemplateSelector:

```
public class ViewModelDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element;
        //System.Data.DataRowView viewModelItem;
        element = container as FrameworkElement;
        // Tests to ensure that both the item and the container are not null, and that the
        // item is of the expected data type.
        if (element != null && item != null && item is System.Data.DataRowView)
        {                
            // Returns the FirstTemplate in the case of a match
            if (item is PersonViewModel)
                return element.FindResource("FirstTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            else
                // Returns the SecondTemplate for other cases
                return element.FindResource("SecondTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
  Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
<Window.Resources>
   <my:ViewModelDataTemplateSelector x:Key="myTemplateSelector" />
</Window.Resources>
<!-- The code omitted for brevity -->
</Window>
```

and to select DataTemplateSelector you should use it at ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelector}" />
```